# making a website local

Tags: web

I'm going to build a website for file manipulations. The idea is that the user will manage to upload his files to the website, and click the "manipulate" button, then he will get the resulted file. Also the user will have to pay in accordance with the amount of files he's trying to manipulate.

The code for the file manipulation is already written in JAVA.

The thing is, some of these files will probably be truly sensitive and private, so users will not be delighted to upload to my site over the internet.

I thought about making a local version of the website, and let the user download it (the local version) to his computer (and the only access the internet will be for the payment action).

But there seem to be two problems:

1. When i'll decide to change anything in my website, it will not affect the local users.
2. The local site will be very easy to "crack" in order not to pay...

This is my first website,

do you have any suggestions of how to solve one of these 2 problems?

Thanks!

Comment: You can provide secure upload over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning question

(1) you would have to implement some update mechanism, for example your "local web site" (which might be a .jar file containing a web server) could check over the internet if a new version is available and then download and install it (however, you should generally ask for user's permission to do so, as many users are not delighted with silently auto-updating software). Concerning question

(2) you might use some code obfuscator to make your compiled java classes more difficult to decompile, and use an encrypted SSL connection for the transactions related to payment (while checking for server certificate to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks by the end user); however any software that a user can have on its computer will be eventually cracked by somebody. Therefore, the best solution is possibly to keep all on *your* server, while securing as much as possible the whole: use encrypted connections with SSL for everything, or even if the files are highly sensitive, provide a public key so users can encrypt their files with GPG (or similar software) before sending them to the site, and encrypt the files to be sent back to the user by using its public key (that he/she has to provide you and that is not critical at all to be transferred over the internet). Also carefully check the security of your web server and all the software running on it, to avoid bugs that might allow somebody to hack into it. Using the encryption with GPG/public keys and only storing encrypted data on your server might be already a good protection (but you have to make sure that it is impossible to get your private key in any way!).